# Eigen cannot create vector from matrix mean directly

Tags: c++, eigen

I am new to Eigen, and I would like to normalize a matrix in rowwise, so my code goes like this:

```
int buf[9];
for (int i{0}; i < 9; ++i) {
    buf[i] = i;
}
m = Map<MatrixXi>(buf, 3,3);
MatrixXi mean = m.colwise().mean();
VectorXi m2 = Map<VectorXi>(mean.data(), mean.cols());
m.rowwise() -=  m2;
```

This will not work, since `m2` is interpreted as vertical, what is the cause of this ?

By the way, I just found that I could not avoid creating a `mean` matrix, which I thinks I could:

```
// this works
MatrixXi mean = m.colwise().mean();
VectorXi m2 = Map<VectorXi>(mean.data(), mean.cols());
// this cannot pass the compilation check
VectorXi m2 = Map<VectorXi>(m.colwise().mean().data(), m.cols());
```

What maybe the cause of this then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but I guess you're looking for `.transpose()`. Also no need to remap the result of `.mean()`:

```
Map<MatrixXi> m(buf, 3,3);
VectorXi mean = m.colwise().mean();
m.rowwise() -=  mean.transpose();
```

or directly use a row vector:

```
RowVectorXi mean = m.colwise().mean();
m.rowwise() -=  mean;
```

or even the one-liner:

```
m.rowwise() -= m.colwise().mean().eval();
```